# Cannot shutdown Ubuntu 16.04.1 & 16.10 (64bit)

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, 16.10

After applying progressive upgrades on kernel (via apt dist-upgrade) the system is unable to turn off after I select shutdown. Disabling the "quiet splash" in grub configuration revealed that system actually freezes after the "reboot: Power down" message.

This problem has been observed on kernels 4.4.0-45, 4.4.0-43 and 4.4.0-38, but not on kernel 4.4.0-31 where the system shuts down normally!

The same problem is also evident by using the Ubuntu 16.10 on a live session after trying to shut down.

System specs: core i5 6600K (skylake), Z170 chipset